# How to force Firefox to download mp3 file?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, download, mp3, file-association

Somehow my Firefox reverted to old behaviour, and now it plays all mp3 files from URL in my browser. I want it to ask for download location.

I have tried several things such as:

- Firefox settings -> Programs -> ... no option for "save as" there. Edit: actually i see "save as" option there now, **but when i select it, it still plays on the browser** even after reopening firefox.
- about:config / media.windows-media-foundation.enabled -> false
- AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\n74u0loi.default\mimeTypes.rdf -> NC:saveToDisk="true"

But I cant get it to work.

Firefox version: 28.0 (newest)

**Edit:** yet not found the solution. still forced to right click every mp3 file...

Comment: I can't advise about firefox settings, but as workaround you may try [FlashGot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/). It allows downloading all files (including `.mp3`s) from page in 3 clicks.

Comment: @LogicDaemon, downloading all files isnt very friendly when i only need one. Those kind of downloaders also have the problem that its very hard to find the file you want to download from the page.

Comment: well, if you usually download few files from page, then yes, this is not applicable.

Answer (score 5):

Firefox Menu => Options => Applications

Choose "Save As" *for (.mp3) (audio/mpeg) **and also for** (.mp3) (audio/x-mpeg)*

Comment: As i edited a while ago, that makes no difference when i selected "save as". (for some reason that option wasnt even there a while ago, maybe because i edited mimeTypes.rdf?).

Comment: I just wonder why people upvote answers that doesnt solve the problem at all. Do they even read comments before upvoting?

Comment: What if the specific MIME type isn't listed there?

Comment: @Rookie they upvote because *it worked for them* or at least they *found answer useful*. But only you can mark question as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Open `about:config` and change `media.play-stand-alone` to `false`.
According to [this answer](https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/1049569#question-reply) on mozilla support, you should change `media.windows-media-foundation.enabled` back to the default value.

Edit: On older versions of Firefox `media.windows-media-foundation.play-stand-alone` helps.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Note that I'm not a topicstarter. For me, there is no option `media.play-stand-alone ` in 31.5.0, actual option name is `media.windows-media-foundation.play-stand-alone`. Default is `true`, and file plays in browser. When I set it to `false`, clicking on the file causes download window to appear. Shall I add `media.play-stand-alone`? Please edit your answer to clarify concerns.

Comment: @LogicDaemon Thanks for the input. I'm not an expert, I just found this question, and somwhere else the answer, so I thpught I put it here. I don't know the difference `between media.windows-media-foundation.play-stand-alone` and `media.play-stand-alone`, I can only assume that `media.play-stand-alone` is for all kinds of media, and `media.windows-media-foundation.play-stand-alone` is for windows media foundation files only? If `media.windows-media-foundation.play-stand-alone` works for you, I gues that is good as well.

Comment: @LogicDaemon - If you don't have `media.play-stand-alone` then your not using the current version of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

A makeshift workaround is to mangle the address, like this:

```
data:text/html,<a href="http://www.example.com">bla</a>
```

Replacing `http://www.example.com` with your actual URL, of course. This results in a link being displayed where you can right click and use “Save Link As”.

Comment: This is not an answer for his question. Although more easy workaround is right clicking on the player or even on the link and select save as in the context menu.

Comment: It's not always possible to do that, for example with server-side redirects.

Comment: @NoNameProvided, yeah that works sure, but its tedious to do multiple times in row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the automatic playing of the MP3 files, so you can download instead of play, and your "about:config" does not have `media.windows-media-foundation`, for example if you have Linux, change

```
media.gstreamer.enabled
```

to false

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please note that while your answer may be correct for Linux, the question was about Windows.